# Localization with Laravel. How it works?

Tags: php, laravel, localization

The Laravel `Lang` class provides a convenient way of retrieving strings in various languages, allowing us to easily support multiple languages. e.g. `Lang::get()` can be used to retrieve localized message.

But according to API documentation (and sources), class `Lang` doesn't have `get()` method or other methods like setLocale() for example. Class `Lang extends Facade` but `Facade` doesn't have that methods too.

Instead class `Illuminate\Translation\Translator` contains all methods we used for localization like get()
Why then we don't use `Translator::get()` or `Translator::setLocale()` but `Lang::get()` ??? How these two classes are connected ?

How can we invoke non-existent methods for the class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is here:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades

The Laravel documentation is pretty comprehensive. If you really want to understand how things work in Laravel, please take some time and read it all.